# GDAL: GFS weather model reprojection issues

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm trying to reproject a grib file using gdal.
The crib file has the following,relevant, info:

```
GEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unnamed",
        ELLIPSOID["Sphere",6371229,0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.125000000000000,90.125000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.1250000,  90.1250000) (180d 7'30.00"W, 90d 7'30.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.1250000, -90.1250000) (180d 7'30.00"W, 90d 7'30.00"S)
Upper Right ( 179.8750000,  90.1250000) (179d52'30.00"E, 90d 7'30.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.8750000, -90.1250000) (179d52'30.00"E, 90d 7'30.00"S)
Center      (  -0.1250000,   0.0000000) (  0d 7'30.00"W,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
```

How can I retroject it to ESPG:4326 using gdal?
When I run "**gdal_wrap -t_srs ESPG:4326**" it seems generating the image, but then run a **gdal_translate** command I get the following Error:

```
RuntimeError: PROJ: webmerc: Invalid latitude
May be caused by: PROJ: webmerc: Invalid latitude
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check the PROJ documentation (the coordinate system/transformation library used by GDAL) to see if it mentions converting between a sphere and an ellipsoid or between 2 ellipsoids when there's no datum information.

I only know two ways. One is to just redefine the definition--treat them as the same. The second is to define a custom transformation like geocentric translations but set the parameter values to zeroes. Running through the math will adjust the latitude values slightly to adjust between the sphere and ellipsoid. The longitude values will remain the same.

It also sounds like the functions don't like the raster's extent being beyond +/-180 and +/-90.

Disclosure: I work for Esri.